# Ищу хорошую, понятную обучалку по Symfony 2

Tags: symfony2

С php-фреймвёрками работал довольно мало. Начальство хочет чтобы я научился программировать на фреймворке Symfony 2. Прохожу сейчас самый простой из курсов, который нашёл на сайте http://symfony.in.ua - Создание блога. Тем не менее для меня он довольно сложный, многие моменты не разъясняются вообще (непонятно откуда берутся переменные, текст как будто переводился машиной и нужно время чтобы понять что вообще автор имеет ввиду). Советовали начать с CodeIgniter и далее перебраться на Симфони, но к сожалению вообще нет времени, скоро писать тест по Симфони. Посоветуйте из собственного опыта хороший курс (может видеокурс) создания сайтов на симфони, желательно на русском, но если нет - можно и на английском, самое важное чтобы человек понимал суть излагаемого а не вслепую повторял.

Comment: Симфони - самый серьезный (и потому самый сложный) PHP-фреймворк. Если вам просто говорят, что через месяц тест - стоит поговорить с начальством о том, что это действительно большая махина, подразумевающая знание многих принципов программирования (например, мой любимый SOLID), и они вряд ли получат в результате то, что хотят. Фидбэк вряд ли будет тем, который хочется, но вы сможете немного повернуть ситуацию к себе. Вообще по симфони есть официальный [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/index.html) на английском, ближайший перевод на русский устарел на три года.

Answer (score 3):

В этих разделах можешь найти полезности: http://forum.sfhub.org/forum/17/izuchenie-symfony/
http://forum.sfhub.org/forum/4/dokumentatsiya/

Answer (score 0):

Если с восприятием английской речи проблем нет, советую посмотреть [эти](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony) видеоуроки. Впрочем, даже если речь не воспринимается, но с чтением порядок - под каждым видео текстовая версия полностью повторяющая речь диктора. Так же на том сайте много других обучалок связанных с Symfony2-3. Далее по мере появления свободного времени советую читать гайды и документацию компонентов с официального сайта.

Помимо этого есть и другие курсы ([пример](https://www.lynda.com/Symfony-training-tutorials/1133-0.html)), но я их не смотрел, так что по ним мне нечего сказать.